# How can I find out what time I put down my iPhone last night? Screen Time usage graph is unreadable with large text. Labels overlap

Tags: iphone, screen-time

I have my phone set up to use large text to reduce eye strain.

Most apps work fine but Screen Time daily graph is unreadable because the numbers on the X-axis overlap:

[image: Screen Time screenshot]

(My morning alarm was going off when I took the screenshot, that's why it says "Rise and shine" at the top.)

How can I find out what time I stopped using the phone last night?

I don't want to fiddle around with making the text small / large every time I want to go into Screen Time.  What are my options for getting this fixed?  Seems like an accessibility issue...

I just want to find out what time I put down the phone last night.

Comment: some hint might be in battery life history

Comment: Have you tried turning you phone to landscape orientation?

Comment: @cmason I just tried turning my phone to landscape orientation, it doesn't do anything in Screen Time

Comment: @AlekseyTsalolikhin mine does. try unlocking the rotation on your phone (control center)

Comment: Sidenote: this is clearly not expected behaviour, you can report the bug to Apple on https://www.apple.com/feedback/

Comment: @KevinGrabher I've reported the bug to Apple. You've anticipated my next question (how do I report bugs to Apple).  Thank you!! :)

Comment: @cmason I've unlocked rotation but Screen Time doesn't rotate for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @anki suggested, I can find out what time I stopped using my phone by checking battery level history:

[image: screenshot of battery level history]

Yesterday I didn't use my phone after 10 PM.

The activity graph is completely readable.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround until Apple fixes this bug you can change the text sIte more easily by going to Settings > Control Center and enable "Text Size".

This way you can control the text size from Control Center (and also change it only for the Settings App).